# What is the standard time (clock) of Physics SE and Physics meta?

Tags: support, profile-page

**What is the standard time of Physics SE and Physics meta.**

What is the clock gauging our profile "**visited X days, Y consecutive**"?

eg. in arXiv, we have arXiv time like this: http://arxiv.org/localtime

**How about Physics SE and Physics meta? Is that EST, the same of New York City?**

This matters, whether **Y consecutive** depends on the mark of date-changing line? **Is it 00:00 of EST?**

Comment: I think you have to do more than visit once per calendar day.  I think you have to visit at least once every 24 hours.  I lost a chance at "Fanatic" on the 97th day during travel and I'm almost certain I visited the site during the calendar day but after the previous day's visit (more than 24 hours had passed).  Perhaps there are more details about how consecutive days are counted somewhere on mother meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dmckee's answer is correct, but note that if you want to see UTC time, you can go to the **achivements tab**:

[image]

Comment: thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 3):

All Stack Exchange sites run on UTC.

Comment: thanks, good to know. :)